# Amazon Product Advertising, How to get items listed by all sellers

Tags: api, amazon-web-services

I want to get all active listed items of all sellers of amazon by UPC. I am using "ItemLookup" api but it returns only 1 result always but i want to return items listed by all sellers.

Detail requirement is to show the matching items of Ebay from amazon. Suppose you input "Iphone" then it search all the items from ebay and it is working fine. Next is to get items from amzon, so i have the UPC no from the ebay api and i m using "ItemLookup" api but it dont returns all the seller items always one.

Thanks